# How to convert URI(from mediastore) into image(Bitmap)?

Tags: android, bitmap

hey i checked out a few questions and almost all of the questions were related to internet and mostly included methods like openConnection()and getInputStream() but mine is related to Media store so i am asking this question again here...
I am able to get the Album URI by using media store and cursor but i do not know how to proceed further
thanx in advance.

i tried

```
Bitmap bitmap=null;
            MediaMetadataRetriever mmr = new MediaMetadataRetriever();


            byte[] rawArt = null;

            BitmapFactory.Options bfo=new BitmapFactory.Options();
            mmr.setDataSource(string);
             rawArt = mmr.getEmbeddedPicture();


             bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(rawArt, 0, rawArt.length, bfo);
```

but didn't help

**Edit** mediastore part.......

```
columns  = new String[]{ android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Albums._ID,
            android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM,
             MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM_ART };
            cursor = 

    getActivity().managedQuery(MediaStore.Audio.Albums.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                columns, null, null, null);


                if(cursor != null){
                    while(cursor.moveToNext()) {
                    SongDetails songs = new SongDetails();
                    songs.song= cursor.getString(1);
                    songs.Path=cursor.getString(2);
                    //songs.Album=cursor.getString(0);
                    //songs.Artist=cursor.getString(1);
                    songdetails.add(songs);
                    }}
                list=(GridView)container.findViewById(R.id.grid_view);
                adapter=new LazyAdapter( songdetails);
```

one such `URI:"/storage/sdcard0/Android/data/com.android.providers./media/albumthumbs/138216121805`

Comment: its Uri, not URI. BitmapFactory + ContentResolver.openInputStream.

Comment: please can you elaborate a bit?

Comment: what is your url exactly ? and did you check if rawArt is null ?

Comment: hey @njzk2 i am fetching the album art location from mediastore(i read in one of the answers that  Uri is returned)....now i want to convert that uri into bitmap.......and the above code worked for me if i was fetching image from a song and its path was known but it is not working in case of media store,i think because path of media file and uri returned may not be the same....

Comment: so do u know how i can fetch bitmap if Uri is known ?

Comment: can you post the code where you fetch the url?

Comment: i have done that please check the code now

Comment: did you look at the content of the uri ? what does it look like ?

Comment: looks like normal path to me....w8 letme show its structure

Comment: Have a look ,updated the code

Comment: that looks like a file path. consider `BitmapFactory.decodeFile();`

Comment: i have tried that too :(

Comment: chech the first part of the code please..

Answer (score 2):

Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), imageUri);

Comment: Hey thanx for your short answer +1 for that but images are yet not being dsiplayed so i think my problem was something else..

Answer (score 2):

The easiest solution is to use a `ContentResolver`:

```
InputStream is = context.getContentResolver.openInputStream(uri);
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
```

Or, a shortcut:

```
Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(context.getContentResolver(), uri)
```

The `context` variable can be an `Activity`, `Service`, application context etc.

Comment: Hey thanx for your short answer +1 for that but images are yet not being dsiplayed so i think my problem was something else..